# Python/Pandas drop row based on current month

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to drop rows in the DF using system date for current month and year
Filter based on below
SAP Version = "70" AND FY = "Current Year" AND Period = "Current Month"

Note - Using system date or pandas date/time function please

Current DF:

```
| Project No | SAP Version | FY   | Period | value    |
|------------|-------------|------|--------|----------|
| 0-01241    | 70          | 2020 | Jun    | 712.95   |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Jun    | 388      |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Jun    | 9        |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Oct    | 11495.68 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Nov    | 164307.7 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Dec    | 106296.3 |
| 0-01241    | 70          | 2020 | Jun    | 1425     |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Jun    | -204.96  |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Jan    | 125754.7 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Feb    | 245261.3 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Mar    | 57879.14 |
```

Expected DF:

```
| Project No | SAP Version | FY   | Period | value    |
|------------|-------------|------|--------|----------|
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Oct    | 11495.68 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Nov    | 164307.7 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Dec    | 106296.3 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Jan    | 125754.7 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Feb    | 245261.3 |
| 0-01214    | 70          | 2020 | Mar    | 57879.14 |
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 3 conditions with compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with `70`, actual year and converted datetime to month string by `%b` and [`Timestamp.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html), then chain all by `&` for bitwise `AND` and last filter by inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')

mask = df['SAP Version'].eq(70) & df['FY'].eq(now.year) & df['Period'].eq(now.strftime('%b'))
df = df[~mask]
```

Altrnative is `'invert'` solution with `eq` to `ne` for not equal, `&` for `|` for bitwise `OR` and removed `~`:

```
mask = df['SAP Version'].ne(70) | df['FY'].ne(now.year) | df['Period'].ne(now.strftime('%b'))

df = df[mask]

print (df)
   Project No  SAP Version    FY Period      value
3     0-01214           70  2020    Oct   11495.68
4     0-01214           70  2020    Nov  164307.70
5     0-01214           70  2020    Dec  106296.30
8     0-01214           70  2020    Jan  125754.70
9     0-01214           70  2020    Feb  245261.30
10    0-01214           70  2020    Mar   57879.14
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find current date in Python using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and use it to filter your dataframe like this:

```
In [40]: from datetime import datetime

In [44]: today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%b-%d') 
In [46]: curr_year = int(today.split('-')[0])
In [48]: curr_month = today.split('-')[1]

In [49]: df[(df['SAP Version'].eq(70)) & (df['FY'].eq(curr_year)) & (df['Period'].ne(curr_month))]
```

Example dataframe:

```
In [66]: df = pd.DataFrame({'SAP Version': [70,70,80], 'FY':[2020,2020,2020], 'Period':['Jun','Aug','Jan']})

In [60]: df 
Out[60]: 
   SAP Version    FY Period
0           70  2020    Jun
1           70  2020    Aug
2           80  2020    Jan

In [59]: df[(df['SAP Version'].eq(70)) & (df['FY'].eq(curr_year)) & (df['Period'].ne(curr_month))]
Out[59]: 
   SAP Version    FY Period
1           70  2020    Aug
```

Comment: @jezrael Fixed. Please check now. `curr_year` needed to be `int`.

Comment: Is it ok now? Please check.

Comment: I am not able to figure out the second mistake. Can you please edit my answer? I am confused.

Comment: thanks, I can help you. why do yo think `ne` is there? OP need `I would like to drop rows in the DF using system date for current month and year Filter based on below SAP Version = "70" AND FY = "Current Year" AND Period = "Current Month"`

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael answer with a slight modification worked magic. Thanks

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')

mask = DF['SAP Version'].ne(70) | DF['FY'].ne(now.strftime('%Y'))  | DF['Period'].ne(now.strftime('%b'))

DF = DF[mask]
```